# problem installing mysqldb for python2.6

Tags: python, mysql

My mysql database is located on a remote machine... So i dont have any local copy of mysql on my local machine.. i get the registry key error... (file not found)...

```
serverKey = _winreg.OpenKey(_winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, options['registry_key'])
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

I think it requires to have a local copy of mysql... How do i install the mysqldb for database residing on another machine???

Answer (score 0):

You will indeed need a local copy of MySQL in order to compile the MySQL extension for Python. [This page](http://www.fuyun.org/2009/12/install-mysql-for-python-on-windows/) seems to contain a step-by-step guide for Windows.

However, you might have some luck with a [pre-compiled MySQL module](http://www.technicalbard.com/files/MySQL-python-1.2.2.win32-py2.6.exe). This should work for Python 2.6.

Comment: hey thank you... This pre compiled module worked... :).. thanks a lot